# Envio de mail con Cronjob y con codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

soy nuevo en Codeigniter y estoy realizando una aplicación web con un formulario donde esos registro se guardan en base de datos, lo que requiere la empresa es que esos registros se envíen a un solo correo establecido con un resumen de todos los registros de hoy por ejemplo, me dijeron que tiene que ser un proceso que se envíe automáticamente. Se que se debe de usar un cronjob ,solo que no se como implementarlo en mi aplicación.

Agradecería vuestra ayuda, os dejo el controlador, el modelo y la vista, no se si ayude pero lo dejo.

CONTROLADOR :

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Empleado extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('empleado_model');
        $this->load->model('parametros_model');
        $this->load->library('MailChimp','email');
    }
    //CARGA DE LOGO DEPENDIENDO DEL HOTE Y CARGA DE LAS VISTAS
    public function index()
    {
         if (isset($_POST['hotel'])){
             $this->session->set_userdata('hotel', $this->input->post('hotel'));
             $this->session->set_userdata('localizacion', $this->input->post('localizacion'));
             $hotel = $this->input->post('hotel');
             $localizacion = $this->input->post('localizacion'); 
         }
         else {
             $hotel = $this->session->userdata('hotel');
             $localizacion = $this->session->userdata('localizacion');
         }
        //Logo del hotel y politcia de privacidad
         switch($hotel) {
             case 'barcelona':
//                 $img='gh-head-logo.png';
                 $nmhotel='Gallery Hotel';
                break;
             case 'malaga':
//                 $img='ml-head-logo.png';
                 $nmhotel='Hotel Molina Lario';
                 break;
             case 'mallorca':
//                 $img='hh-head-logo.jpeg';
                 $nmhotel='Hotel Honucai';
                 break;
             default:
//                 $img='gh-head-logo.png';
                 $nmhotel='Hotel';
            }

        //Logo de la ubicacion y politcia de privacidad
         switch($localizacion){
             case 'sintonio':
                 $img2 = 'sintonia-logo.png';
                 $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                 El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                 Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                 Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                 Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web ';
                 $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                 break;
             case 'top_gallery':
                 $img2 = 'ubi-form-gh.png';
                 $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                 El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                 Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                 Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                 Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                 $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                 break;
             case 'Matiz':
                 $img2 = 'modal-resta-ml.png';
                 $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                 El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                 Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                 Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                 Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web http://www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                 $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                 break;
             case 'top_molina':
                 $img2 = 'ubi-form-ml.png';
                 $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                 El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                 Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                 Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                 Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                 $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                 break;
             case 'Salicornia':
                 $img2 = 'salicor-resta.png';
                 $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                Asimismo, nos autoriza a que sus datos personales sean cedidos a la empresa del grupo GALLERY CENTER, S.L. (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona), con idénticas finalidades.
                                Adicionalmente, únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. por escrito (C/ Gabriel Roca s/n, 07638, Colonia de Sant Jordi, Mallorca - Illes Balears) o por e-mail a galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com.
                                Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web http://www.hotelhonucai.com/aviso-legal';
                 $url ='www.hotelhonucai.com/aviso-legal';
                 break;
             case 'top_honucai';
                 $img2 = 'ubi-form-hh.png';
                 $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                 El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                 Asimismo, nos autoriza a que sus datos personales sean cedidos a la empresa del grupo GALLERY CENTER, S.L. (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona), con idénticas finalidades.
                                 Adicionalmente, únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                 Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. por escrito (C/ Gabriel Roca s/n, 07638, Colonia de Sant Jordi, Mallorca - Illes Balears) o por e-mail a galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com.
                                 Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                 $url ='www.hotelhonucai.com/aviso-legal';
                 break;
             default:
                 $img2 = 'ubi-form-gh.png';
                 $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                 El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                 Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                 Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                 Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                 $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
         }

         $data['title']='Gallery Hoteles';
//         $data['img']=$img;
         $data['nmhotel']=$nmhotel;
         $data{'hotel'}= $hotel;
         $data['img2']= $img2;
         $data['localizacion']= $localizacion;
         $data['condiciones']= $condiciones;
         $data['url']= $url;
         $this->load->view('comun/header',$data);
         $this->load->view('formulario/formu_views',$data);
         $this->load->view('comun/footer',$data);
    }

    //INSERCION DE DATOS DEL REGISTRO EN BASE DE DATOS Y VALIDACION DE CAMPOS
    public function insertar()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre','nombre','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('apellidos','apellido','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ciudad','ciudad','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ubicacion','ubicación','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('terminos','terminos','callback_terminos');


        $hotel = $this->session->userdata('hotel');
        $localizacion = $this->session->userdata('localizacion');


        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
            $datos['nombre']=set_value('nombre');
            $datos['apellidos']=set_value('apellidos');
            $datos['email']=set_value('email');
            $datos['ciudad']=set_value('ciudad');
            $datos['ubicacion']=set_value('ubicacion');
            $datos['terminos']=set_value('terminos');


            switch($hotel) {
                case 'barcelona':
//                    $img='gh-head-logo.png';
                    $nmhotel='Gallery Hoteles';
                    break;
                case 'malaga':
//                    $img='ml-head-logo.png';
                    $nmhotel='Hotel Molina Lario';
                    break;
                case 'mallorca':
//                    $img='hh-head-logo.jpeg';
                    $nmhotel='Hotel Honucai';
                    break;
                default:
//                    $img='hh-head-logo.png';
                    $nmhotel='';
            }

            switch($localizacion){
                case 'sintonio':
                    $img2 = 'sintonia-logo.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'top_gallery':
                    $img2 = 'modal-top-gh.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'Matiz':
                    $img2 = 'modal-resta-ml.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'top_molina':
                    $img2 = 'modal-top-ml.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'Salicornia':
                    $img2 = 'salicor-resta.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Asimismo, nos autoriza a que sus datos personales sean cedidos a la empresa del grupo GALLERY CENTER, S.L. (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona), con idénticas finalidades.
                                    Adicionalmente, únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. por escrito (C/ Gabriel Roca s/n, 07638, Colonia de Sant Jordi, Mallorca - Illes Balears) o por e-mail a galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com.
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.hotelhonucai.com/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                case 'top_honucai';
                    $img2 = 'modal-top-honu.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Asimismo, nos autoriza a que sus datos personales sean cedidos a la empresa del grupo GALLERY CENTER, S.L. (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona), con idénticas finalidades.
                                    Adicionalmente, únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con PORT COLONIA, S.L.U. por escrito (C/ Gabriel Roca s/n, 07638, Colonia de Sant Jordi, Mallorca - Illes Balears) o por e-mail a galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com.
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.hotelhonucai.com/aviso-legal';
                    break;
                default:
                    $img2 = 'gh-modal.png';
                    $condiciones = 'En cumplimiento del Reglamento Europeo 2016/679 del 27 de abril en materia de Protección de Datos de Carácter Personal, presta su consentimiento a que GALLERY CENTER, S.L. recoja y trate sus datos personales con el fin de mantenerle informado, incluso por medios telemáticos, de servicios y ofertas propios de la empresa.
                                    El suministro de sus datos es voluntario, siendo la base jurídica para su tratamiento el consentimiento prestado. 
                                    Únicamente tendrán acceso a sus datos terceros con los que medie obligación legal o contractual para la prestación de servicios técnicos, entre otros.
                                    Podrá ejercitar sus derechos de acceso, rectificación, supresión, oposición y portabilidad, así como que se limite el tratamiento de sus datos, poniéndose en contacto con GALLERY CENTER, S.L por escrito (C/ Rosselló 249, 08008 Barcelona) o por e-mail (galleryhoteles@galleryhoteles.com).
                                    Para más información consulte nuestra política de protección de datos disponible en recepción o en la web';
                    $url ='www.galleryhotel.com/es/aviso-legal';
            }

            $data['title']='Gallery Hoteles';
//            $data['img']=$img;
            $data['nmhotel']=$nmhotel;
            $data['hotel']= $hotel;
            $data['img2']= $img2;
            $data['localizacion']= $localizacion;
            $data['condiciones']= $condiciones;
            $data['url']= $url;
            $this->load->view('comun/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('formulario/formu_views',$datos,$data);
            $this->load->view('comun/footer',$data);

        }else{
            $firma= str_replace(" ", "_", $this->input->post('nombre')).'_'.str_replace(" ", "_", $this->input->post('apellidos')).'_'.date('Y-m-d-H_i_s').'.png';
            $data = array(
                'nombre' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
                'apellidos'=>$this->input->post('apellidos'),
                'email'=> $this->input->post('email'),
                'ciudad'=> $this->input->post('ciudad'),
                'fecha'=> date('Y-m-d  H:i:s'),
                'condiciones'=> 1,
                'firma'=>$firma,
                'ubicacion'=>$this->input->post('ubicacion'),
                'hotel'=>$this->input->post('hotel')
            );

            // Variables para guardar el canva //
            $img = $this->input->post('datos-img');
            $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
            $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
            $img_data = base64_decode($img);
            $ruta= $this->parametros_model->get_parametros('ruta_firmas');
            $file = $ruta. $firma;
            $success = file_put_contents($file, $img_data);
            $image=str_replace('./','',$file);

            //MAILCHIMP
            $list_id = '0f61ec2abc';//EL HOTEL DEBERÁ PONER EL ListID DONDE GUARDARÁ LOS MAILS AL IGUAL QUE EN APLICATION/CONFIG/CONFIG LINEA 525
            $MailChimp = new MailChimp('APIKEY-us12');
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
                $this->mailchimp->verify_ssl = false;
            }
            $result = $this->mailchimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'merge_fields'  => [
                    'FNAME' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
                    'LNAME'=>$this->input->post('apellidos'),
                    'CIUDAD'=>$this->input->post('ciudad'),
                    'UBICACION'=>$this->input->post('ubicacion'),
                    'NMHOTEL'=>$this->input->post('hotel'),
                ],
                    'status'=> 'subscribed',
            ]);


            $this->empleado_model->insertar($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('hotel',$hotel);
            redirect('empleado');
        }
    }

    //CALLBACK DE LA VALIDACION DE TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES
    public function terminos($data)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['terminos']))return true;
        $this->form_validation->set_message('terminos','Se deben aceptar los términos y condiciones');
        return FALSE;
    }


}
```

Comment: una cosa que veo es que `$condiciones` podrias declararlo global ya que es siempre el mismo string y te ahorraria bastantes lineas de codigo

Comment: Es corrector, pero la aplicación tiene 3 hoteles y cada hotel tiene 2 ubicaciones un total de 6 y solo para un hotel las condiciones son diferentes, por eso he puesto bastantes lineas de código, si conoces una forma mejor, soy todo oídos.

Comment: Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es crear una función en tu controlador que tenga el proceso de recolección de los datos que se van a enviar y que posteriormente haga el envió del mail.

En el CRON de tu cpanel ya nadamas configuras la tarea a esa dirección y el periodo de tiempo que hay mismo te lo pide.